# How can I transform nested for-loops with if-statements into a list comprehension?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested, list-comprehension

Im completely new to list comprehensions, and I know how to make a basic one. However, how can I transform these nested for-loops with an if-statement, into a list comprehension?

fyi: `listDicts1` and `listDicts2` are lists of dictionaries (did not want to provide them as they are very large).

```
  for d in listDicts1:
        for d2 in listDicts2:
            if d['name'] in d2['text']:
                  d['person'].append(d2) 
        print(d)
```

My attempt:

```
new = [d2 for d in listDicts1 for d in listDicts2 if d['name'] in d2['text']]
```

Comment: This is very non-trivial to transform and is not worth it. Your original code is concise and readable while the resulting list comprehension will be anything but.

Comment: The problem here is that list comprehensions are used to create a new list, whereas you want to populate an existing one. If you were fine creating a new list, your way at the bottom is perfectly ok. To populate `d['person']` though, your first way at the top is fine.

Comment: Ok! was trying to make my code "faster" , ill keep it in the original way then. Cheers !

Comment: the big caveat is that your code _modifies_ the dicts in `listDicts1`. That can be an unacceptable side-effect, or the desired outcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to agree with @Aplet123's comment that the OP's initial code is concise and readable. But there is one **important caveat: it does modify in place the dicts of `listDicts1`**, which in my book is a big no-no: imagine that an unsuspecting user (yourself, in three months) has a bunch of dicts, puts them in a list and passes that to your function, only to (later, during debugging and much head scratching) discover that the original dicts themselves have been sneakily modified in place as a side-effect of your function... (I guarantee you, that's happened in the best families).

So, if instead you'd like to keep the initial dicts unchanged, which in much safer and IMHO always preferable, then you would have to generate new dicts whenever there is a modification needed (when your condition is True).

**Version 1**: pure comprehensions (but also always makes a new dict):

```
listDicts3 = [{
    **d,
    **{'person': d.get('person', []) + [
        d2 for d2 in listDicts2 if d['name'] in d2['text']
    ]}} for d in listDicts1]
```

**Version 2, preferred**: only makes new dicts when needed (others are just copy-through by reference):

```
persons = [[d2 for d2 in listDicts2 if d['name'] in d2['text']] for d in listDicts1]
listDicts3 = [
    {**d, **dict(person=d.get('person', []) + p)} if p else d
    for d, p in zip(listDicts1, persons)
]
```

Note that both of the above start with an empty list if `person` was not yet a member of `d`.

Test example:

```
listDicts1 = [dict(name='fred', person=[]), dict(name='paul', person=[])]
listDicts2 = [dict(text='paul ate an apple'), dict(text='anne reads a book')]

# ... (one of the code snippets above to make listDicts3)

listDicts3
# output:
[{'name': 'fred', 'person': []},
 {'name': 'paul', 'person': [{'text': 'paul ate an apple'}]}]

listDicts1
# out (shows it is unchanged)
[{'name': 'fred', 'person': []}, {'name': 'paul', 'person': []}]

# your code, with side-effect
for d in listDicts1:
    for d2 in listDicts2:
        if d['name'] in d2['text']:
              d['person'].append(d2) 
    print(d)
# out:
{'name': 'fred', 'person': []}
{'name': 'paul', 'person': [{'text': 'paul ate an apple'}]}

# HOWEVER:
listDicts1
# out:
[{'name': 'fred', 'person': []},
 {'name': 'paul', 'person': [{'text': 'paul ate an apple'}]}]
```

Note: you can avoid the side effect and keep your code almost as is:

```
for d in listDicts1:
    d = d.copy()
    for d2 in listDicts2:
        if d['name'] in d2['text']:
              d['person'].append(d2) 
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm inferring quite a lot from the way you've structured your loop here, it would be easier if you could provide a minimal example.

```
listDicts1 = [{'name': 'A', 'person': []}, {'name': 'B', 'person': []}]
listDicts2 = [{'text': ['A', 'B']}, {'text': ['B', 'C']}, {'text': ['C', 'A']}]
[d1['person'].append(d2) for d1 in listDicts1 for d2 in listDicts2 if d1['name'] in 
d2['text']]

print(listDicts1)

"[{'name': 'A', 'person': [{'text': ['A', 'B']}, {'text': ['C', 'A']}]}, {'name': 'B', 
 'person': [{'text': ['A', 'B']}, {'text': ['B', 'C']}]}]"
```

Whether this is a good idea to do or not, is up for debate, my only objection to it would be readability.

Comment: like the OP's code, this also has the side-effect of modifying the dicts in `listDicts1`. This is almost always a _very.bad.idea_.

Comment: Conceivably, this seems like a logical usage of code question, not a software engineering question. With appropriate copy, as you detail, this comprehension is perfectly safe. Logically, this is the answer the OP asked for.

Comment: yeah but without the copy, it is not safe; when you see a small fire, stomp on it.

Comment: As you note above, modifying the list in place could be the desired outcome. I don't disagree with your sentiments generally though.

Comment: Both answers are acceptable, but I learnt most from Pierre D's, thank you for your effort!